# How to specify an input setter as optional in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to specify an optional setter input on my Directive -

```
// works fine
@Input()
public foo?: number;

// I want achieve similar optional status for this -
@Input()
public set baz(val: number): void {
    // some code
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @JsNgian - Wasn't trying to solve a problem, just wanted it to be apparent to the reader. Panagiotis' answer cleared it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional class fields like `public foo?: number;` are just a typescript thing, meaning the variable can either exist and be of type `number` or not exist at all so it would be of type `undefined`. It is just a type shortcut for typescript so you don't write explicit `public foo: number | undefined`

As for functions. Typescript allows optional parameters too, so it would be

```
public set baz(val?: number): void {
    // some code
}
```

Again it would be a shortcut for

```
public set baz(val: number | undefined): void {
    // some code
}
```

I don't know if I could help you as you don't specify what the problem is, but I hope I helped you understand optional in class fields and method parameters.

Comment: @panagiotis-bougiokos I wasn't aware that the ? was just syntactic sugar! I wasn't facing a problem per se, just wanted to know what would be the best way of conveying that my setter input is optional to readers. Thank you!